# ajax $_POST data then redirect to new page

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, post

I have been going crazy for the last 2 weeks trying to get this to work. I am calling a MySQL Db, and displaying the data in a table. Along the way I am creating href links that DELETE and EDIT the records. The delete pulls an alert and stays on the same page. The EDIT link will POST data then redirect to editDocument.php

Here is my PHP:

```
 <?php
 foreach ($query as $row){
        $id =  $row['document_id'];
        echo ('<tr>');
        echo ('<td>' . $row [clientName] . '</td>');
        echo ('<td>' . $row [documentNum] . '</td>');

        echo "<td><a href='**** I NEED CODE HERE ****'>Edit</a>";

        echo " / ";
        echo "<a href='#' onclick='deleteDocument( {$id} );'>Delete</a></td>";
        // this calls Javascript function deleteDocument(id) stays on same page
        echo ('</tr>');   
 } //end foreach
 ?>
```

I tried (without success) the AJAX method:

```
<script>
function editDocument(id){
  var edit_id = id;
     $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'editDocument.php',
        data: 'edit_id='edit_id,
        success: function(response){
          $('#result').html(response);
        }
     });
}
</script>
```

I have been using `<? print_r($_POST); ?>` on editDocument.php to see if the id has POSTed.

I realize that jQuery/AJAX is what I need to use. I am not sure if I need to use `onclick`, `.bind`, `.submit`, etc.

Here are the parameters for the code I need:

1. POSTs the $id value: `$_POST[id] = $id`
2. Redirects to editDocument.php (where I will use $_POST[id]).
3. Does not affect other `<a>` OR any other tags on the page.
4. I want AJAX to "virtually" create any `<form>` if needed. I do not
   want to put them in my PHP code.
5. I do not want to use a button.
6. I do not want to use $_GET.

I don't know what I am missing. I have been searching stackoverflow.com and other sites. I have been trying sample code.  I think that I "can't see the forest through the trees." Maybe a different set of eyes.  Please help.

Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE:**

**According to Dany Caissy, I don't need to use AJAX. I just need to $_POST[id] = $id; and redirect to editDocument.php. I will then use a query on editDocument.php to create a sticky form.**

Comment: Why not a simple link to `edit.php?id=123`? What's wrong with a GET here?

Comment: what error are you getting? check your javascript error log and your php error log. also, you're sending the POST variable `edit_id`, not `id`, which you said you wanted.

Comment: Otherwise I suppose you could use jQuery to dynamically create a form, set the action and create a hidden field with the id, then submit the form. But Ajax won't work for what you want to do.

Comment: also, not sure if you can pass a string argument for `data` like that ... try `data: {id: edit_id},` instead of `data: 'edit_id='edit_id,`

Comment: Try changing `$('#result').html(response);` to `$('html').html(response);` in the script you tried.  It looks like you are sending the right data and getting a full page back, so why not replace your current page with that new page?  (I'm not positive that'll correctly replace the current page, you might end up nesting html tags in themselves)

Comment: @Jason P: Don't want a page with GET data bookmarked. @sgroves: error is that no value in $_POST; I am using `<? print_r($_POST); ?>` on editDocument.php to dump the $_POST data. @BlargleMonster either the page does not redirect to editDocument.php, or $_POST is empty and the URL shows as editDocument.php?tableau=59

Answer (score 2):

AJAX is used when you need to communicate with the database without reloading the page because of a certain user action on your site.

In your case, you want to redirect your page, after you modify the database using AJAX, it makes little sense.

What you should do is put your data in a form, your form's action should lead to your EditDocument, and this page will handle your POST/GET parameters and do whatever database interaction that you need to get done.

In short : If ever you think you need to redirect the user after an AJAX call, you don't need AJAX.

Comment: Then I don't need to use AJAX. I just need to $_POST[id] = id; and redirect to editDocument.php. I will then use a query on editDocument.php to create a sticky form.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` in your `$.ajax();` request here

```
<script>
function editDocument(id){
  var edit_id = id;
     $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'editDocument.php',
        data: 'edit_id='edit_id,
        success: function(response){
          $('#result').html(response);
        }
     });
}
</script>
```

it should be like this

```
<script>
function editDocument(id){
  var edit_id = id;
     $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'editDocument.php',
        data: {edit_id: edit_id},
        success: function(response){
          $('#result').html(response);
        }
     });
}
</script>
```

note the `'edit_id='edit_id,` i changed, well for a start if you wanted it to be a string it would be like this `'edit_id = ' + edit_id` but its common to use a object like this `{edit_id: edit_id}` or `{'edit_id': edit_id}`

and you could also use a form for the edit button like this

```
<form action="editDocument.php" method="POST">
   <input type="hidden" name="edit_id" value="272727-example" />
   <!-- for each data you need use a <input type="hidden" />  -->
   <input type="submit" value="Edit" />
</form>
```

or in Javascript you could do this

```
document.location = 'editDocument.php?edit_id=' + edit_id;
```

That will automatically redirect the user

Comment: I do not want to use a $_GET, and I want to use a script that turn links into POSTs just insert forms (and the form tags) dynamically.

Comment: `echo "<td><a href='**** I NEED CODE HERE ****'>Edit</a>";
echo " / ";
echo "<a href='#' onclick='deleteDocument( {$id} );'>Delete</a></td>";` creates EDIT/DELETE in a single table cell. There are other forms that the css will mess up the table formatting.

Comment: Well, simple answer you cannot make a `POST` request to a different page without a FORM unless you use Ajax but then you wouldn't go to the page

Comment: Can you have a rediredt at the end of the function?

Comment: in javascript ofcourse just use `document.location = 'newPage.php';`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17707500/how-to-prevent-user-from-bookmarking-urls @Ric

Answer (score 0):

Given your comment, I think you might be looking for something like this:

`<a href='#' class="editLink" data-id="123">Edit</a>`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.editLink').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $link = $(this);
        $('<form/>', { action: 'editdocument.php', method: 'POST' })
            .append('<input/>', {type:hidden, value: $link.data('id') })
            .appendTo('body')
            .submit(); 
    });
});
```

Now, I don't necessarily agree with this approach. If your user has permission to edit the item with the given id, it shouldn't matter whether they access it directly (like via a bookmark) or by clicking the link on the list. Your desired approach also prevents the user from opening links in new tabs, which I personally find extremely annoying.

**Edit** - Another idea:

Maybe when the user clicks an edit link, it pops up an edit form with the details of the item to be edited (details retrieved as JSON via ajax if necessary). Not a new page, just something like a jQuery modal over the top of the list page. When the user hits submit, post all of the edited data via ajax, and update the sql database. I think that would be a little more user-friendly method that meets your requirements.

Comment: You have `data-id="123"` as a string, where the id is in the variable $id. I need to use something like `data-id= <? echo $id; ?>` although that does not work. I also agree about not being able to open the links in other tabs/windows, but that is just for the EDIT, because I do not want the user opening 4 EDIT pages to edit the same record and updating the wrong one. I need to have this be "stupid-proof."

Comment: You're missing the quotes on your example: `data-id="<? echo $id; ?>"`. Not sure if that was just a typo here. What part exactly is not working?

Comment: @ Jason P: `echo "<td><a href='editDocument.php' class="editDocument"  data-id= "<? echo $id; ?>">Edit</a>";` gives me an error:Parse error: **syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in /index.php on line 241** Do not want to use Javascript/JSON/AJAX, all my queries use PDO.

Comment: Oh, you're switching your quote types and closing literals too soon: `echo "<td><a href='editDocument.php' class='editDocument' data-id='<? echo $id; ?>'>Edit</a>";`

Comment: fixed the syntax, but the link to editDocument.php does not work. `echo "<td><a href='editDocument.php' class='editDocument'  data-id= '" .  $id . "'>Edit</a>";`

Comment: Yes, or you can add use self-closing syntax as I've done in my edit. My bad.

Comment: By not working, I mean it stays on index.php, does not redirect to editDocument.php.

Comment: Then there is an error occurring. Check your console and network tab, and debug the javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue with you. I also wanted to redirect to a new page after ajax post.
So what is did was just changed the success: callback to this

```
success: function(resp) {
        document.location.href = newURL; //redirect to the url you want
    }
```

I'm aware that it defies the whole purpose of ajax. But i had to get the value from a couple of select boxes, and instead of a traditional submit button i had a custom anchore link with custom styling in it. So in a hurry i found this to be a viable solution.